# Ruby, how to get numbers after $ symbol

Tags: ruby

Having an array:

```
price = ['$6.95', '$7', '$10.50']
```

I need to get all numbers from it like: 6.95, 7, 10.50

```
price[0].match('\d+')[0].to_f
```

returns 6. I expect 6.95

Comment: 6.95 is not an [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)...

Comment: my bad `price[0].match('\d+')[0].to_f` returns 6.0 anyways

Comment: that is not a valid array.

Comment: "." is not a valid number either `\d+` means digit. So your match is effectively `["6","95"]` but the `MatchData` is only going to store the first match in this case so `"6"`

Comment: Can you provide a sample Ruby snippet that's valid code and more accurately represents the data you're dealing with?

Comment: This is not an exact match for the nominated exemplar, although it is close.

Comment: what do you want `$7` to return?

Answer (score 1):

`['$6.95', '$7', '$10.50'].map { |price| price.match(/\d+\.?\d{0,2}/)[0].to_f }
=> [6.95, 7.0, 10.5]`

The regex here supports any number of digits, an optional decimal point, and up to two trailing numbers (cents). If you have commas in your prices (like $1,000) you'll need to be a little bit more clever around the `\d+` part.

Comment: `price[1..-1].to_f` returns the same array as this answer.